# Data-modelling tools for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, dto, odm

Even though MongoDB is a schema-less DB but there is a requirement in my project where I have to map my classes to the Database objects and prefer to have the data modelling for the same. Please suggest some Data-modelling tools for MongoDB to map the DB to Classes and Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to model your applications and persist your data in MongoDB. So it depends on what framework/language are you using for application.

I did a quick web search to get these ODM (Object-Document-Mapper) options recommended to work with MongoDB for some of the popular languages.

**ruby**

- https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/
- http://mongomapper.com/

**java**

- https://github.com/mongodb/morphia
- http://hibernate.org/ogm/

**python**

- http://mongoengine.org/
- http://api.mongodb.com/python/1.6/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I did some research on DBSchema and Hackolade. Hackolade is really cool but very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

[Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) is a data modeling tool for MongoDB and Mongoose (ODM)